# how do I get some values in my array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
 Array
    (
        ["name1"] => 15
        ["name2"] => 25
        ["name3"] => 35
    )
```

I have used `array_keys` to get the names from this array. Now I need to get the second part of the array, the numbers, and store them in another variable. I can't find a good solution for that.

Comment: What's the exact expected result in this second variable ?

Comment: Do a simple foreach? or `$value = $array['name1'];` It's simple php and there's dozen of guides / ways to do it if you just try and google

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean but perhaps `array_keys( $arr )` to get an array just of the keys and `array_values( $arr )` to get an array of just the values. Then you could use `implode`?

Comment: Non of the answers mention using implode to get a delimited string value as @RamRaider says. This is how I interpreted the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get all array keys:

```
$var = array_keys($array);
```

Get all array values:

```
$var = array_values($array);
```

Iterate over all array elements:

```
foreach($array as $key =>$value) {
    echo "Key : $key, value: $value<br/>";
}
```

Comment: well.. i never heard from array_values... my bad sorry :) but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use key and value combination of foreach loop like:

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$value){

$variable1 = $key;
$variable2 = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **foreach** loop

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$values){

  $var1 = $key;
  $var2 = $value;
}
```

OR

for getting keys

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
```

for getting values

$values = array_values($array);

Answer (score 1):

just use array_values() function

example

```
<?php
    $a=array("Name"=>"Peter","Age"=>"41","Country"=>"USA");
    print_r(array_values($a));
?>
```

output

```
Array ( [0] => Peter [1] => 41 [2] => USA )
```

refer: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_values.asp

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over the array, and add to another array just the numbers...

```
$anotherVariable = array();   
foreach($array as $key =>$value) {
   echo "Key:".$key." - value:".$value."<br/>";
   array_push($anotherVariable, $value);
}

print_r($anotherVariable);
```